# Update current jsp page through servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

As a part of a web project in college, I'm going to code a webshop.

I have a Java servlet where I add items to a basket. This servlet can be called from different JSP sites where i have items listed. What i cant figure out is how to refresh the page.

I have been googling around, and found 2 proposals;

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "1");
```

or

```
response.sendRedirect("/demo.jsp")
```

I can't really use solution 2, because I dont know what item I have to redirect to, as it called from several JSP sites, and I just want to stay on the same page.

And from what I understand from solution 1, that isn't just a 1 time refresh, but a script that keep updating the site with one-second intervals.

So can anyone help me: How can I refresh the site just once, when an item is added to my basket?

Comment: May be you should try "Ajax" for this task.

Comment: Correct; this is what Ajax is for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refresh the page you can call reload function

**Example**

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
```

Code courtesy http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm

Comment: My project is limited to using jsp and java servlets. So i need a command line i can put into my java servlet which refresh the page, exactly the same way as response.sendRedirect("/demo.jsp") redirects you when called from the servlet :)