# Refreshing a page in JSP Servlet

Tags: javascript, html, reload

This question has been asked before.

I am calling a servlet from a JSP Page and and after certain processing in the backend I want to refresh the same JSP Page again. Referring to this [Update current jsp page through servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001553/update-current-jsp-page-through-servlet) , I tried using both the methods, but it doesn't seem to work.

What is the way to do it, as the UI will reflect my changes in the backend only after reload.

## Answer

Just using reload location.reload() in Javascript as suggested.

Comment: This isn't really a JSP or Servlet question; it's an HTTP, HTML, and JS question since you want to do it client-side.

Comment: How do you call location.reload() in Javascript AFTER you get results in JSP? JavaScript can't access the changed values in JSP, right?